# Configuring ACM.exe and ACMBROWSER.exe tools

Tags: appfabric, access-control

I'm trying to configure the acm.exe and the acmbrowser.exe tools in order to manage my service namespace. I'm using the AppFabric Labs so I set the host to 'accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com'.

My service namespace is 'homebuilder'. After setting all these details (along with the mgmtkey) in the app.config file I get an error. It seems these tools are trying to access https://homebuilder-mgmt.accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com which cannot be resolved. I'm using v2 of the ACS. Are the endpoints changed from v1 in this version and if yes how can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoints are changed in the labs version (v2). Anyway, it seems the whole administration can now be made from the web UI of the ACS. Here's a link to the scenario I wanted to implement http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20Simple%20Service&referringTitle=Samples.